# move_base does not load plugin

Tags: navigation, move-base, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm just begin to use ROS for about 3 months to do a project in my university. I am having a problem with move_base server since it seem not able to come up. When i run rostopic list there a few topic appear (https://imgur.com/LlIR150). I also try send a simple goal with the code finding in https://bit.ly/36MHiFC  (ROS tutorial sending a navigation goal) but nothing happen (https://imgur.com/WHLMcah). Since there are no error show up i dont know what i have done wrong

Can anyone help me with this

I'm very appreciated your help

This is my terminal when i run the move_base server (https://imgur.com/Szk0QmB)

And this is my move_base launch file (https://imgur.com/qovh44U)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367094/move_base-does-not-load-plugin/) by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-12-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2020-12-15**:
@hiep127 for any text please don't use images as the text in images can't be copy and pasted. Please see [the support page](http://wiki.ros.org/Support#Do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At least, `odom`, `map`, and `sensor_topic` are missing.
Also read the `move_base` documentation.

http://wiki.ros.org/move_base#move_base-1

---

Originally posted by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) with karma: 1908 on 2020-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-07**:
Thank you for your reply

yeah it seem like the tf from map to base link is missing cause i have tried runiing all those topic already and still nothing happend

**Comment by [miura](https://answers.ros.org/users/59801/miura/) on 2020-12-07**:
You may try doing the following set: https://github.com/yuthikasagarage/2D-Autonomous-Slam-Rover

**Comment by [hiep127](https://answers.ros.org/users/64783/hiep127/) on 2020-12-07**:
Okay thanks <3